# Comparing two dates in excel gives wrong result

Tags: excel-2010

I'm doing a date comparison using the IF function and I get wrong results. Here's a screen:

[image]

First two columns have dates in them. They are formatted as 'Date' format. The formula is:

```
=IF(U19<V19;TRUE;FALSE)
```

First row gives a wrong result while the second is ok. I double checked and there are no extra spaces in the cell.

Comment: Looking at the information you've provided there's nothing obviously wrong.  The first dates could be interpreted as either 7th April, or 4th July and 12th April or 4th December but would still be in an earlier year.  If you add a day to the date it calculates correctly?  i.e. `=U19+1` returns 08.04.2021?

Comment: Correct. If I add +1 to date it shows the next day as expected.